# Pinned memory with offset in OpenCL

Tags: c, buffer, opencl

So I'm reading data in a file using `mmap()` as follows :

```
unsigned char* mapped;
mapped = mmap(0,size,PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE,input,0);
```

Then I created my host buffer and device buffer for pinned memory :

```
cl_mem pinned_buffer_input = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, size, mapped, NULL);
cl_mem buffer_input = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, input_size, NULL, NULL);
```

Within a `for` loop I am :

- mapping the buffer :

  ```
  void *pinnedMemory = clEnqueueMapBuffer(cmd_queue, pinned_buffer_input, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_WRITE, header[3]+b*input_size, input_size_cur, 0, NULL, &ev, NULL);
  ```
- enqueuing the buffer :

  ```
  clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cmd_queue, buffer_input, CL_FALSE, 0, input_size_cur, pinnedMemory, 0, NULL, &ev);
  ```
- unmapping the object :

  ```
  clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(cmd_queue, pinned_buffer_input, pinnedMemory, 0, NULL, &ev);
  ```

Here `mapped` contains the whole file and is of size `size`.
What I want is to have buffers of size `input_size` (or `input_size_cur`, same thing to simplify) to send data by blocks. So the offset is `header[3]+b*input_size` where `b` is incremented in the loop but it copies wrong data.

**EDIT** : If I don't initialize `pinned_buffer_input` with `mapped` then I can get a pointer to the host buffer with `clEnqueueMapBuffer()` and copy the data of `mapped` to that place :

```
memcpy(pinnedMemory, mapped+header[3]+b*input_size, input_size_cur);
```

By doing so it works but I want to avoid the `memcpy` as it is in a `for` loop and it creates huge delays in my program. To solve this problem I wanted to use the `offset` parameter of `clEnqueueMapBuffer()` but it screws up.

**EDIT 2** : with `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR` instead of `CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR` the result is correct but it takes ages to create `pinned_buffer_input`.

Comment: "but it doesn't work that way". Does it crash? Does it not copy?

Comment: EDITED : it copies wrong data that I can't interpret.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got a clear picture to tell why is not working but some guesses are:

- Are you waiting for the unmap/Write to complete?
- How are you checking the data was writen properly? If you are reading it back, how are you reading it back? Maybe the problem is there as well.

Comment: The data is used for a process which I know the result. I've edited the post to try to give a better understanding of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might mean to use CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR instead of CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR. The former indicates that the application wants the OpenCL implementation to use memory referenced by host_ptr as the storage bits for the memory object, the latter specifies that the application wants the OpenCL implementation to allocate memory from host accessible memory. Since you already have a pointer to memory, the former seems correct.